# Is there a way to capture screenshot of an element in appium for python?

Tags: python, appium, screenshot

I want to capture screenshots by elements in appium similar to the one in selenium. I am using python. Could not find much about this, is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use the Appium `driver.get_screenshot_as_base64()` command described in the documentation: http://appium.io/docs/en/commands/session/screenshot/

Now you should have a screenshot of the full page. You can ask the element its location and crop the screenshot. This is described for Python and Selenium in detail here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15018372/how-to-take-partial-screenshot-with-selenium-webdriver-in-python

Although I didnt try it myself I think the cropping should work the same for Appuim based elements and screenshots.

Answer (score 0):

This post is a little old, but for everyone else who ends up here appium does have this built in.

First find the element you want to screenshot (you can use the `self.driver.find_element()` function). Then the web element returned has different properties including "screenshot_as_png".

There are several options in my autocomplete (but I didn't see any documentation readily available but I did find https://stackoverflow.com/a/47959716/20523639):

- Function: screenshot()
- attribute: screenshot_as_base64
- attribute: screenshot_as_png